# jQuery beforeScroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a beforeScroll event in jQuery? Or can this type of event be replicated at all?

We have a scenario where we need perform an event before a div with overflow:scroll has been scrolled. The problem with using the .scroll event is that this is raised after the div has been scrolled rather than before.

Comment: You mean after the scroll is performed but before the actual scrolling has occured?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no such event.  The scroll event cannot be cancelled (for obvious reasons) and I would speculate that it fires after the action so that the *scrollTop* and *scrollLeft* properties are accurate when accessed.

Possible workarounds might be to capture the *mousewheel/DOMMouseScroll* events and the keydown events for page up, page down, up, down, etc. keys.  There's no 100% method, though - you'll never be able to stop the user from interacting with the browser's scrollbar components.  The only true solution there is to roll your own scrollbars.

If you're just looking to find the amount the user scrolled, you could set a timer to store the current *scrollLeft/scrollTop* in a variable and then check them vs the new values in the *scroll* event.

Comment: So can I grab the event when the user clicks on the browser's scrollbar before the .scroll event is fired? I.e. does the keydown event fire before the scroll event?

Comment: @Robert: no, the scrollbar is a UI element and will not fire mouse events.  The keydown event will fire before the scroll event because it can be cancelled to prevent scrolling with the keys if you like.  Like I said, there's no 100% method, the best you can do is build your own scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in a crude way that turned out to be surprisingly un-laggy:

I update the position myself after checking that the position is within the range that I want, using position=fixed, and alter the top value.