# stop the jquery scrollwheel scrolling the document

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

**EDIT:**

Perhaps I am approaching this wrong - does anyone know any way of stopping the page from scrolling with the mouse wheel? Can this even be disabled?

--

I have a div container filled with smaller div's which animate when the mouse wheel is scrolled. This is not a div with overflow:hidden, and it has no scrolling areas - it is just a simple jquery animation (the animation works fine btw).

Unfortunately despite all my best efforts I cannot stop the entire page from scrolling whilst the mouse is inside the container div.

I am using Brandon Aaron's mousewheel plugin for jQuery (which is supposed to solve my problem, but unfortunately it isnt).

Here is my javascript:

```
$('#containerDiv').mousewheel(function(event,delta,deltaX,deltaY){
    /* all of this is supposed to stop the page from scrolling...  but it doesnt*/
    event.bubbles=false;
    event.cancelBubble=true;
    if(event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    if(event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.stopImmediatePropagation) event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(document).blur();
    $(this).focus();

    /*this function just animates the divs inside the container divs*/
    animateDivs(delta);
});
```

Ive been through these questions already:

[Prevent scrolling of parent element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802467/prevent-scrolling-of-parent-element)

[stop mousewheel's continued effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159327/stop-mousewheels-continued-effect)

[stop scrolling of webpage with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670487/stop-scrolling-of-webpage-with-jquery)

and none of them seem to help.

Can anyone offer a better solution to this problem?

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/1107651) to a similar question worked for me

Comment: $.mousewheel doesnt scroll elements. Its add scrolling elements by mousewheel. Your example it does. (MouseWhell scrolling is disabled. Scrollbar scrolling is enabled)  http://jsfiddle.net/A8tjk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use galambalazs's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/1102223) as [Guilherme Torres Castro answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11460033/1102223). But it doesnt cancel `scroll` event. If you want cancel scroll event, you must add it.
My [fiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kubedan/qaxDR/) inspirate by [ntownsend's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2469710/1102223).

Problem of this solution is "blicking"(hiding/showing) scrollbar. So I add scroll to actual scroll position on window.onScroll event and my [FINAL SOLUTION is here](http://jsfiddle.net/kubedan/qaxDR/3)

Final solution has problem when I try scrolling, but event beforeScroll doesnt exist https://stackoverflow.com/a/3352244/1102223